Read a random line from a .txt file and then set it to a variable for further processing
I want C# to read one random line from a .txt file (low two digit numbers of entries on the largest files with less than 35 characters).
I used File.AppendAllText to write to .txt files before. I tried a few solutions (e. g. "File.ReadAllLines, but then I don't know how to pick one random line), but they don't seem to work for me here. Unfortunately, I'm not the best at coding.
using System;
using System.IO;

public class CPHInline
{
    public bool Execute()
    {
        //This will get the folder path for the file that is supposed to be read in format "X:\Folder\Folder2\".
        string pathF = CPH.GetGlobalVar<string>("File path", true);
        //This contains the file name which changes sometimes. This variable combines the folder path and file path to the final path.
        string path = $"{pathF}Medium.txt";
        //The string "message" is supposed to contain the random read line.
        string message = //The read random line from the .txt file is supposed to be a the value of the variable.
        //From here on out, this is the part where the random line get's processed further. 
        string voice = CPH.GetGlobalVar<string>("TTS speaker", true);
        
        CPH.SendMessage(message, false);
        CPH.TtsSpeak(voice, message, false);
        return true;
    }
}




e. g. "File.ReadAllLines, but then I don't know how to pick one random line

For random line, you can generate a random number (using Random.Next()) and get line at that index.
Like:
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

Random rand = new Random();
int index = rand.Next(0, lines.Length);

string message = lines[index]; // random line


Thanks, seems to work fine. Although, I assume you mean "File.ReadAllLines" instead of "Files.ReadAllLines".

@StefanBraun oh, sorry that was a typo.

I believe instantiating a new Random every time its needed can expose you to deterministic behavior on some versions of the .NET Sdk, you should instead use a random seed, or reuse the Random object.
